# Summing or substituting based on conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data-manipulation

I have a coding hurdle that I am not sure how to go about.

My dataset looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2","id2","id2"), 
                 "time" = c(1,2,4,5,2,3,4,6),
                 "Treatmentid" = c("1", "2", "1a","3", "1", "4","4a","3"), 
                 "Val" = c(2,3,5,1,2,7,4,1))
```

Where "id" indicate a subject, "Treatmentid" indicate the treatement the subject is receiveing and "Val" is the value of the treatement.

Usually, treatments are persistent over time, hence I would like to sum them for each individual to calculate the total treatment it is receiving for every time point.

The issue is that some treatments those denoted by "a", are actually substituting, rather than adding to the treatment without an a.

Hence I would like my final dataset to look something like this

```
final <- data.frame("id" = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2","id2","id2"), 
                 "time" = c(1,2,4,5,2,3,4,6),
                 "Treatmentid" = c("1", "2", "1a","3", "1", "4","4a","3"), 
                 "Val" = c(2,3,5,1,2,7,4,1),
                 "totVal" = c(2,5,8,9,2,9,6,7))
```

Whereby the total values are summed up for different "Treatementid" (i.e. for id1 at time 2, totVal= 2+3= 5). 
While they are substituted when treatments are amended (i.e. for id1 at time 4, totVal= 5+3= 8). Here, the value of "Treatmentid 1a" (5) has replaced the value of "Treatmentid 1" (2).

I hope this is clear.

I thank you all in advance for your help

Comment: For `Treatmentid 1a` for `id1` if it is substitution then shouldn't the `totVal` be 7 (5 + 2) instead of 8 ? Also how do you get values 6 and 7 for last 2 rows?

Comment: No, because treatment "1a" (Val=5) takes the place of treatment "1" (Val=2). While treatement "2" persist (Val = 3). Hence totVal= "1a"+"2"= 5+3= 8.

Comment: Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Will there be only one treatment with "a" in it for each `id` ? OR there could be multiple, how those would be treated if there are many?

Comment: No, unfortunately, there can be many treatments with "a". For instance at some point also 2 can become "2a". Multiple treatments are amended over time

Comment: Do you know how I could go about this? any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my logic of how to achieve what you want. It's quite convoluted and might take a long time on large data sets. If anyone can improve on my solution, I'm happy to oblige.

```r
library(dplyr) # for bind_rows function
```

First we split the dataframe into two by the group `id` in the first column. This gives a list of two dataframes. We are then going to loop over this list to get the sums.

```r
mylist <- split(df, f = df$id)
```

Next we initiate the variables needed in the for loop. We need a list to keep track of the original ids and we need a list to keep track of the sum. We also need an indexer for extracting values and we need another indexer for the list of data frames, which are `x` and `df_num` respectively.

```r
ids <- list()
vals <- list()

x <- 1

df_num <- 1
```

In the code below, a nested for loop is used to calculate the rolling sum of the `Treatmentid`. The loop goes through each element in `mylist`, then there is a nested for loop to go through each value in the `Treatmentid` column.

For the first row, the sum is equal to the value. So an if test is used here to check if the current iteration of the for loop is equal to the first value in `Treatmentid` column. If it is, then the first sum is just equal to the first value in `my_df$Val`. Then the id is saved, the for indexers are incremented and the for loop goes to the next iteration.

After that, I use `grepl` to check if the value in `Treatmentid` has no letter in it. If the test evaluates to `TRUE`, then that means there is no 'a' in it, thus there is no substitution. Therefore, the sum proceeds as normal. If it is `FALSE`, then there is an 'a' in it and hence it's a substitution. The 'a' part is deleted leaving just the number, and then we search the list of ids for where the number equals the id number, we get the index and save it to `a`. This will be the index of the row with the value to substitute in the original data. We subtract that and add the substitution value.

Lastly, outside of the inner loop, we unlist the values to a new column called `totval`. Then this dataframe is saved to `mylist`.

```r
for (my_df in mylist) {

  x <- 1

  for (j in my_df$Treatmentid) {

    if (j == my_df$Treatmentid[1]) {
      vals[[1]] <- my_df$Val[1]
      ids[[x]] <- j
      x <- x + 1
      next
    }
      if (grepl("^[[:digit:]]+$",j)==TRUE) {

      ids[[x]] <- j

      vals[[x]] <- vals[[x-1]] + my_df$Val[x]
      x <- x + 1

    } else {

      a <- which(sapply(ids, function(y) substr(j, 1, nchar(j)-1) %in% y))
      vals[[x]] <- vals[[x-1]] - my_df$Val[a] + my_df$Val[x]
      x <- x + 1

    }
  }

  my_df$totVal <- unlist(vals)
  mylist[[df_num]] <- my_df
  df_num <- df_num + 1
  }
```

Once the loop is done, convert the list of dataframes to a full dataframe with `bind_rows()` from `dplyr`.

```r
Final <- bind_rows(mylist)
```

I saved your desired output to `final`, and I check if the dataframe created in the loop is equal to what you want using `identical()`, and the result is `TRUE`.

```r
identical(Final, final)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is surely far beyond what I was able to do. I will try it on the data, I need to do some adjustment first, but I'll let you know soon. Is this code sintax able to deal with missing data?

Comment: You're welcome, let me know how it goes. The code won't deal with missing data since adding NA to a number returns NA. You can add an if test to check if the value is NA before summing. If it is NA then go to the next iteration.

Comment: Not sure I know where in the loop i should put the `if(Val==NA)`. Also,"Treatmentid" can have different lengths (1a,111a or 13a). the key identifier is the "a" but the loop seems to be relying on character length. would you have any recommendation on adapting it? Sorry for these very specific questions but I am really not sure how to use loops.

Comment: How should NAs be treated? If you are ignoring them then just remove them with ```df <- df[complete.cases(df),]```. That will only keep rows that do not have any NAs anywhere, therefore any observation with row where Val has an NA will be removed. Btw, you check for NAs with ```is.na()``` and not with ```==```. If you are not ignoring them then what does the NA represent? For your later question, I'll need to have a bit of a rethink but the logic shouldn't change too much.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me with this. did you come up with some ideas to focus the function on the presence of the "a" rather than on the character length?

Comment: I edited my answer about 2 hours ago. Instead of checking for the length of the character, I now check if the character is only numbers with ```grepl()```. Everything else is the same.